# Photoelectric effect question

Tags: kinetics, electrons, photochemistry

[image: Photoelectric question]

My attempt:- 1)At 0.68e15 Hz frequency of light,Metal A gives 7.2eV Kinetic Energy(KE).

2)At 1e15 Hz frequency of light, Metal B, gives 6eV Kinetic Energy.

3) At 1.1e15 Hz frequency of light, Metal C gives 5.5eV Kinetic Energy.

4)At1.2e15 Hz frequency of light, Metal D gives 5eV Kinetic energy.

Now $KE_{max}=(\frac{hc}{\lambda}-\phi)$ where c= speed of light, $\lambda$=wavelength of light and $\phi$= work function of metal.

Now $7.2eV=(4.14e-15eVs \times 0.68e15 Hz- \phi)$ for metal A.The wavelength of light is 441 nm. Likewise we can compute wavelength of light incident on Metal B, C and D.

But we don't know the work functions of Metal A,B, C and D.

So, how to answer this question?

Comment: For each of the 4 metals, the work function energy is given by the abscissa intercepts, using E = h $\nu$. Those are the minimum energies, for each metal, to just get electrons free, but with no kinetic energy. Should be easy now!

Comment: I just did what I said in my other comment and the answer is B. Use the information given to compute the work function energy, in Joules, then use the energy of a photon expression in my other comment!

Comment: @EdV, Yes, my computed answer also is in agreement with your answer.

Comment: Excellent! Now I don’t have to use my analogy using prisons (metals), prisoners (incarcerated electrons), a sack of money tossed over the prison wall (absorbed incident photon energy), bribing the guard to escape (paying the work function energy), and having extra money for moving around after escaping (kinetic energy of the electron). ;-)